# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with JNI on MacOs

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to learn about JNI but at the first program, I wrote it gives following exception when I run the compiled Java program.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prtmsg in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at MyMain.<clinit>(main.java:5)
```

this is my directory files list 
[Screenshot of direcotry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME1ht.png)

This is the java file

```
class MyMain{

    public native void printmsg();
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("prtmsg");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyMain mm = new MyMain();
        mm.printmsg();
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please post source code a text not as image

Comment: @TheScientificMethod done !

Comment: Does it work if you specify the path to the directory containing the .so file, using `-Djava.library.path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this when using MacOS to compile the c code we have to use the following command :

```
gcc -shared -o libLibraryName.dylib CProgramName.c -fPIC
```

here as the name of the compiled code it should append with lib at the begining and .dylib and the end.

When loading it in java

```
 static{
        System.loadLibrary("LibraryName");
    }
```

without using libLibraryName.dylib just use LibraryName. Extract the lib and .dylib !